# How to set the active branch using LibGit2Sharp?

Tags: c#, lib2gitsharp

I want to create a local branch from master, commit stuff into it and then push the changes to the newly created branch. This is what I did:

```
string branchname="jodel";
string _repoPath="C:\\gitstuff";
var _author=new Signatur("bot","@bot", DataTimeOffset.Now);

// Clone Repository 
Repository.Clone(_settings.Config.Git.Url, _repoPath, new CloneOptions {  BranchName="master"});

// Create Branch:
var repo=new Repository(_repoPath);
Remote remote = repo.Network.Remotes["origin"];
var localBranch = repo.CreateBranch(branchname);
repo.Branches.Update(localBranch, 
b => b.Remote = remote.Name, 
b => b.UpstreamBranch = localBranch.CanonicalName);

// Commit
//    Create dummy file:
 File.WriteAllText(_repoPath + "/" +Guid.NewGuid().ToString()+".txt", "Hallo, Welt");
//    Add to Index:
var status=repo.RetrieveStatus();
foreach (var file in status.Untracked) repo.Index.Add(file.FilePath);
repo.Index.Write();
//   do Commit
repo.Commit("hi there", _author, _author);
// Push
var pushOptions=new PushOptions { CredentialsProvider=...};
repo.Network.Push(repo.Branches[branchname],options)
```

This is what happens:
Cloning succeedes. Creating that branch also works. Pushing that branch to the remote repository also work. BUT: the Commit is not not happening to my created branch but to the master branch which I cloned at the start.
So all I am missing is one of the following:

- How to set my created branch as "active"
  OR
- How to inform the Commit which branch to use

None of the examples/docs from lib2gitsharp or even intellisense give me a clue what to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you work with git locally in command line: after creating a branch, you need to check it out.

> $ git checkout -b iss53
>
> *Switched to a new branch "iss53"*

This is shorthand for:

> $ git branch iss53
>
> $ git checkout iss53

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging

---

So, after creating a branch in your code, you need to run a `Checkout` command.

```
Commands.Checkout(repo, localBranch);
```

https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/wiki/git-checkout